# Populating 2 variables with user-entered form data and sending them to PayPal

Tags: commerce, payment-gateways

**Problem**

Hi, when a user submits a payment form on my site I need to populate two variables $comment1 and $comment2 with the values of other information the user supplied but I'm unsure how to accomplish this in Drupal so that those variables get sent to PayPal.

**Example Scenario**

So, for example, a user enters their name in the checkout form and their organization in another field. When the user submits the form to paypal for payment processing we want the `$comment1` field to get their `$organization` value and for the `$comment2` field to get their `$fullname` value.

We want these to be sent to PayPal along with all the other information that gets sent to PayPal because the PayPal manager can read and utilize values in variables called `$comment1` and `$comment2`.

**Question**

My question is, what's the best way to accomplish this?

**Assumption**

I assume it involves hooking into and changing some code in a function in the contributed module somewhere. Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you're using [commerce_paypal](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_paypal) **WPS**, you'll need to hook

```
HOOK_commerce_paypal_wps_order_form_data_alter(&$data, $order){}
```

in a custom module. there you can extend the $data array like

```
$data['on3'] = 'your_property_name';
$data['os3'] = 'your_property_value';
$data['on4'] = 'your_other_property_name';
$data['os4'] = 'your_other_property_value';
```

or exchange data like

```
$data['organization'] = $data['fullname'];
```